# How to handle non tabular data?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have site terms, about and contact modules on my website. I want to be able to change these items via CMS and not via changing .ASPX pages every once in a while. My question is how to store this data ? I used to store this kind of data in SqlServer but i always thought it is an overkill since data is a single row with different columns especially when in some cases i just need one column.

How do you handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a poor-mans CMS in the past for this type of thing by reading an xml file, however, [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) is an excellent CMS you may want to look at.

Comment: In that case I would an xml file or appsettings in the web.config if a database is not required.